# Sobrepor uma img estática com a imagem de webcam

Tags: html, css

Bem, é um projeto simples, um "site" o qual acessa a web cam, captura a imagem e envia para um servidor.

[image: Exemplo do projeto]

Consegui implementar a web cam com o seguinte código HTML5 com javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
        <meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
        <meta content="Web Cam" name="title">
        <title>Web Cam</title>

<style>
            #container {
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 500px;
                height: 375px;
                border: 10px #333 solid;
            }
            #videoElement {
                width: 500px;
                height: 375px;
                background-color: #666;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

        </video>
    </div>
    <script>
        var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
        }

        function handleVideo(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        function videoError(e) {
            // do something
        }
    </script>
    <script>// Put event listeners into place
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                    video = document.getElementById("video"),
                    videoObj = {"video": true},
            errBack = function (error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }
            else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }
        }, false);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu problema atual é sobre como colocar essa imagem de fundo e ajustar a câmera para que fique nesse tamanho 3x4 e que ao pressionar um button ela tire a foto e deixe estático no lugar do crachá.

A parte de enviar a foto para um servlet e etc, eu consigo fazer mas essa parte inicial está muito difícil para mim.

Comment: Teu problema não é com o mesmo do título "Colocar imagem de webcam dentro de uma img estática", teu problema é com a sobreposição da imagem, faça um título que condiz com o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: paccamicio não consigo entender aonde do teu html está a imagem do crachá

Comment: Opa, eu deletei ele do código, ele estava em uma <div> mas simplesmente não funcionava, tentei de tudo sobreposição de <div> etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção é usar o plugin [jQuery Webcam](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam) para capturar a imagem, atribuindo-a como source de um elemento `img` de sua página no método (ou evento) `onSave`.

Seu código seguiria mais ou menos a seguinte lógica:

```
$("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function(data) { 
        var col = data.split(";");
        var img = image;

        for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
            var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
            img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
            pos+= 4;
        }

        if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            pos = 0;
        }

        // Coloque a imagem no elemento img nesse ponto.
    },
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
});
```

Comment: Estarei verificando logo mais nessa madrugada e passo o feedback, mas seguindo essa lógica já acho que pode resolver.